# unable to see dynamically created pages in visual studio 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010

With reference to [VS2010 ASP.NET: How can I set a breakpoint in my Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310013/vs2010-asp-net-how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-in-my-javascript)

I was using IE10 but was unable to see some properties in it. So i switched back to IE8. But now I am not able to debug my jquery. Also i am unable to see the dynamically created pages in the solution explorer where i can put break points. Please help.
I tried putting `debugger;` as mentioned in lot of solutions but still was not able to see the dynamically created pages.

Comment: its ok you(someone) gave my question -1 but please answer it as well..i am stuck on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4498361/2190878 here also it is written that a 'Script Documents' folder is created. But i am not able to get that folder. How to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Re-register all dll's present in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug using regsvr32. 2. IE->Tools->Internet Options->Advance tab->uncheck 'Disable script debugging'. Restart IE.